# Как отображать меняющиеся данные flask python

Tags: python, flask

Пытаюсь отобразить данные с текущей ценой -bittrex.com. я использую flask 3.6 и python 3.6 on pythonanywhere
вот код прилоения фласк :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests



app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def price():
     url='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-nav'
     z=[]
     r = requests.get(url)
     x=r.json()
     e1=x['result'][0]['Ask']

     return render_template('index.html', price=e1)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

Search: <input type="text" id="search_form_input"></input>

<div id="text"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",

    })
      .done(function( price ) {
        $("#price-box").val(price)
      });
}, 1000 * 60);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

ошибка -500 Internal Server Error полагаю проблема с pythonanywhere  и ajax
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">

Подскажите как решить проблему .
Может есть другой способ показывать данные с запросов на сайте ?

Comment: Исправьте `@app.route('/')` на `@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`. По умолчанию роуты работают только через GET методы, [подробнее.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#http-methods)

Comment: @godva  исправил , к сожалению та же ошибка

Comment: а в какой директории хранится index.html?

Comment: @godva в той же ,что и flask приложение . По умолчанию  pythonanywhere берет из это же папки . Но template тоже пробовал указать - не помогло

Comment: pythonanywhere берет шаблоны из папки templates. Можете проверить это прописав строку `print("TEMPLATE_FOLDER = {}".format(app.template_folder))` после создания app. А затем в логах увидеть директорию в которой flask ищет шаблоны.

Comment: @ godva          добавил -                                                                                      
return render_template('index.html', price=e1 ,template_folder='/home/crypto_compare/index.html') , не помогло

Comment: Создайте директорию templates в директории проекта, и положите в нее index.html. После этого перезагрузите веб приложение.

Comment: @ godva спасибо  Вам, помогло , тупил на ровном месте